# When reported current confignode is not ready and all query progress got timeout, what configuration should be checked in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

From yesterday’s afternoon, my query progress in Apache IoTDB suddenly all get timeout. Error information is like  `DriverTask 20240226_053350_08273_3.2.0.0 is aborted by timeout`. Since I use the cluster version of IoTDB, I checked the cluster settings first, and found that the confignode connection reported failure, like `Failed to connect to ConfigNode TEndPoint(ip:tsdb3, port:10710) from DataNode TEndPoint(ip:tsdb1, port:6667), because the current node is not leader or not ready yet, will try again later`. However, these error messages did not give me any idea of why this problem happened. Therefore, I want to ask if anyone can give me an idea on what configuration should I check now to narrow down the possible reason for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I seem to have encountered similar problems in previous tests. After troubleshooting, it seems that the configuration file has been changed. You can check the configuration file `tsdbx` and `hosts` in Apache IoTDB, and resume them to default settings if you change anything.